# Read and process multiple .TIFF files using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have problem on read and process multiple tiff file using MATLAB since I am beginner in MATLAM software. I have 300 of tiff images with same dimension. I want to loop the process, however, I cannot get it. Until now, I only change the file-name every time to read and process. I still don't get where should start. Can anyone help me. Here I attach my coding.

```
filename=('brd06330_s0239.tif');
fileinfo=imfinfo(filename);
Nfiles=numel(fileinfo); 
Cloud=cell(Nfiles,1); 

   for n=1:Nfiles

     A=imread(filename);
     [rimg cimg]=size(A);
% Read by band (for this task only use band 1)    
      B1Channel = A(:, :, 1);


 %  A=imread(filename);
 % [rimg cimg]=size(A);

%for channel 1
 W_countB1 = sum(sum(B1Channel == 0)) % W= water
 NW_countB1 = sum(sum(B1Channel > 0)) % NW= non water (cloud and land)


   end

   %save in text format(excel)
   d=[W_countB1,NW_countB1]
   colname={W_countB1,NW_countB1}
   xlswrite('brd06330_s0239',d)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `dir('*.tif')`, that will get you a list of all TIFFs in your directory, then you can loop the whole thing like you wanted.

it would look something like:

```
files=dir('*.tif');

for i=1:length(files)

   A=imread(file(i).name);

   %//... whatever you want to do with your TIFFs

end
```

hope that helps.